# Is there a better way to update a value in one dictionary inside a list of dictionaries than to use linear search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say we have below list of dicts:

```
objList = [{"name": "tom", "value": 2}, {"name": "jerry", "value": 2}]
```

If I want to update the `value` of `jerry`, I would do something like the below:

```
for obj in objList:
    if obj['name'] == "jerry":
        obj['value'] = 3
        break
```

Is this a good way of updating the value in a particular dictionary in the list? If we have a huge list, is it still going to perform well or is there any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, I don't see a more performant alternative

Comment: Looks like the fastest option possible for such a task!

Comment: Your problem is that your data model is terrible. Instead of `objList = [{"name": "tom", "value": 2}]`, you should have `objList = {"tom": 2}`. Then you could implement the logic efficiently.